Decomposition of many particle coordinate system into translation, rotation, and vibration
Consider the space $\left(\mathbb{R}^3\right)^N$ of configurations of $N$ three-dimensional points.
Given for each point a "mass" $m_n$ and a reference configuration $x^o_n$, is it always possible given an arbitrary configuration $x_n$ to find a decomposition
$$
x_n = X + O \left( x^o_n + \Delta x_n \right)
$$
where:
$$
X = \frac{\sum_{m=1}^N m_m x_m}{\sum_{m'=1}^N m_{m'}}
$$
is the center-of-mass, $O$ is a matrix representing a proper rotation, and the $\Delta x_n$ are a set of vectors representing "distortion" of the framework $x^o_n$ in the sense that
$$
\sum_{m=1}^N m_m \Delta x_m = 0
$$
(i.e. $\Delta x_n$ does not change center of mass) and
$$
\sum_{m=1}^N m_m \left( x^o_m \times \Delta x_n \right) = 0
$$
(i.e. $\lambda \Delta x_n$ does not generate rotation about center of mass as $\lambda \to 0$)?
If so, is this decomposition unique?

This decomposition is not always unique.
Consider a $N=4$ particle system $\text{X}\text{Y}_3$ where three of the particles have the same mass.
We adopt as the reference structure the $C_{3v}$ symmetric pyramidal structure (e.g. methane $\text{NH}_3$):

For our purposes it will suffice to consider a plane containing $\text{X}$, the center of mass $\text{CoM}$, and one of the $\text{Y}$:

Suppose for simplicity that the particles $\text{Y}$ make an angle of $45^\circ$ with the symmetry axis.
We can then easily construct two "normal modes" of collective displacements that are pure distortions in that they keep the $\text{CoM}$ fixed and the do not generate rotations.
The first mode is a collective displacement is a "uniform compression" where the particles $\text{Y}$ all move towards the $\text{CoM}$ at the same rate $r_{\text{Y}}=y$, while the particle $\text{X}$ also moves towards the $\text{CoM}$, but at a rate $r_{\text{X}}=x$.
The second mode is an "umbrella motion" which is identical to the first except for the particles $\text{Y}$ move in a direction perpendicular to the line $\overrightarrow{\text{CoM}\,\,\text{Y}}$ joining the $\text{CoM}$ to the reference position of the particle $\text{Y}$.
These modes by design do not alter the position of the $\text{CoM}$, and we can see that they do not induce rotations by noting that they both are of the totally symmetric $A_1$ symmetry with respect to the $C_{3v}$ point group, while the three modes generating rotations are of $A_2$ symmetry and the doubly-degenerate $E$ symmetry.
We now consider a distortion along the first mode for one unit of time so that the particles all coincide at the $\text{CoM}$, and then a distortion along the second mode for another unit of time so that each particle has a position obtained by a reflection about the symmetry axis:

The system is now in a configuration that is related to the reference configuration by a rotation of $180^\circ$ about the symmetry axis, while at the same time given by a pure distortion of the reference configuration without any rotation.
The coordinate decomposition described in the original question is therefore not unique.
It's clear there is a connection between the non-uniqueness of the decomposition and the existence of a configuration where all the particles coincide which is invariant under all rotations, but I can not formulate precisely what this connection is.
